# ionic 2 front end unit testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ionic2

```
<div class="titlebox">
    <div class="listHead">
    <h1>British Brewing Company</h1> 
            </div>
```

How can we check whether the heading "British Brewing Company" is present or not by unit testing in ionic-angular 2?

Comment: Unit testing ?? what is that means

Comment: Unit testing is a software development process in which the smallest testable parts of an application, called units, are individually and independently scrutinized for proper operation.